# Not Accessible Image Returning a Response

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a .gif image which is only accessible if I am on Wifi. On a certain domain like mydomain.mysite.com/myimage.gif the image is not accessible.

But on my production environment the image some how becomes accessible and returns the following response:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x156c5200> { URL: } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
    "Cache-Control" = "max-age=86400";
    "Content-Length" = 554;
    "Content-Type" = "image/gif";
    Date = "Wed, 26 Mar 2014 14:47:53 GMT";
    Etag = "\"030329e4e9c91:11c4\"";
    "Last-Modified" = "Tue, 09 Jun 2009 13:17:20 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/6.0";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }
```

My Objective C code is as follows:

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:currentEnvironment];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response
                                      error:&error];



    if(response != nil) return YES;

    return NO;
```

**SOLUTION:**

I believe this is the solution: The cachePolicy is implemented.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:currentEnvironment];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response
                                      error:&error];
```

Comment: Could the image be coming from the cache?

Comment: That is what I am wondering! But I am not exclusively caching the image. Also, it works on the other domains but not on production.

Comment: iOS will use the cache policy as set in the http header by default, unless you tell it not to use the not use any cache policy.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the above code with my answer. The NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData on NSURLRequest does the trick.

Comment: Just post the answer as a real answer to your question and accepted, then you question will show up as answered when someone searches. You have to wait some time before you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The production server was sending the Cache-Control headers which was caching the response. The solution is to specify NSURLRequest to not cache which is implemented below:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:currentEnvironment];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response
                                      error:&error];
```